# Incremental build with go build (or go install) does not work

Tags: go

I have a go project and not much exposure to Go! I am issuing the command `go build` or `go install` repeatedly, with absolutely no changes or modifications to the source code

Example:

```
${GOLANGBIN}/go build -v -i -o $(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)/bin/main src/main
```

I am expecting that after the first time, my binaries not get updated at all. However, after each build, my binaries are up to the date with the latest timestamp.

Is Go capable of only building what needs to be built (since last time) and not build what is already up to date?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to upgrade to go 1.13
I was using 1.09